# Stopping all current played youtube videos

Tags: flash, youtube, action

Is there way to make function in Action Script, or any other language, to stop all currently played youtube videos in current Tab?

Here's example, There are 10 youtube video objects on the site, i wanna have one button, to simply make them stop playing.

So, is there way to do this, and if yes, could you give any advices/directions where i can learn the technique?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take a look at [YouTube Player API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html#Overview)